# Configuring TLSSendDomainSecureList for Exchange Online with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

We are replicating an on-premises setup on Office 365.

As per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/set-transportconfig?view=exchange-ps the command `Set-TransportConfig` the switches:

`-TLSSendDomainSecureList` and `-TLSReceiveDomainSecureList`

are **only available on-premise**.

Any idea of the equivalent Office 365 PowerShell command please?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can achieve the same configuration by using a combination of the [Set-ReceiveConnector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/set-receiveconnector?view=exchange-ps) and [Set-OutboundConnector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/set-outboundconnector?view=exchange-ps) cmdlets.

For **receive**, use a combination of the `-RecipientDomains`, `-TlsDomain`, and `-TlsSettings` parameters.

Similarly for **send**, use the `-DomainSecureEnabled`, `-RecipientDomains`, `-RequireTls`, `-TlsDomain`, and `-TlsSettings` parameters.